# Trouble Booting MacBook Air (2018 Model)

Tags: macos, bootable-disk

Hi everyone so I bought a MacBook Air off someone on Facebook market place and it was working fine. but stupid me was sketched out about putting my information in until I factory reset myself thought I deleted the OS but looks like I deleted the boot file I can't seem to get back to disk utility to perform first aid. internet recovery will load then after the time count-down I get error 1008F or if I start up normally get the flashing folder with the question mark which indicates the boot file is gone or damaged I really hope to fix this does anyone have any ideas. all help is welcome thank you.

Comment: Hey, just tried what they implemented doesn’t seem to work I still get the flashing folder with question mark

Comment: Pls provide more details about your problem (macOS version, screenshots, etc.) and what you have done to fix it so far.